# Any good undergrad analysis research problems?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, research

I'm looking for some ideas for longer and more research type problems to do in real analysis. The coursework we get is not very demanding and it would be nice to have some longer and harder projects to do on the side. At the moment i have background in basic real analysis, (limits and sequences, differentiation and continuity, integration, sequences of functions and series), linear algebra, and basic set theory and construction and the axioms of real/rational/natural numbers, but as i'm studying and intend to study more all the time, any suggestions about more advanced topics are also highly appreciated and would give something to work towards and do later on. Something that would require a bit more time and effort and looking into, something a bit more researchier than proving specific limits and differentiation rules.

Comment: Do you mean new research/open problems, or advanced topics? If the latter, you might start studying measure theory.

Comment: You could just proceed through the material at a faster pace. Try learning calculus on manifolds for example.

Comment: Maybe spend some time compiling a collection of examples and counterexamples for the various theorems you have learned. If a theorem says "if A and B, then C", then find examples where only one of A or B holds and C is false. And find an example where C holds but A and/or B do not.

Comment: @Hayden measure theory sounds good. But yeah i meant more research type problems to do on the side, as i feel like it also gives a better grasp of the learned material when it has to be used and applied outside the specific coursework context.

Comment: @Bungo That sounds interesting, thanks!

Comment: Have a look at Liouville's theorem on formal antiderivatives and try to make sense of it and solve true cases (search the Web, this is really hard). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the problem of finding a function which is differentiable, but whose derivative is not continuous?

You could look it up, and there's a standard example ($f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin(1/x),x\gt0\\0,x\le0\end{cases}$, I believe).

But in addition to studying it, maybe you could look for other examples.